# The css calc function is not adding a gutter to the page as expected- Chrome Version 122.0.6261.112 (Official Build) (x86_64)

Tags: html, css

I have 2 elements on a page that I am using floats to position side by side. I want a gutter or space between them. I am using the css calc function to achieve that, but it is not working in the latest version of Chrome or Safari. Here is my css
//main.css

```css
   :root {
      box-sizing: border-box;
   }

   *,
   ::before,
   ::after {
     box-sizing: inherit;
   }

   body {
     background-color: #eee;
     font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   }

   header {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #0072b0;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
   }

   main {
    display: block;
   }

  .main {
     float: left;
     width: 70%;
     background-color: #fff;
     border-radius: 0.5em;
    }

   .sidebar {
     float: left;
     width: calc(30% - 1%);
     padding: 1.5em;
     background-color: #fff;
     border-radius: 0.5em;
    }
```

And here is the html markup

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </head>
   <body>
    <header>
        <h1>Franklin Running Club</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main class="main">
            <h2>Come join us!</h2>
            <p>
                The Franklin Running club meets at 6:00pm every Thursday
                at the town square. Runs are three to five miles, at your 
                own pace.
            </p>
        </main>
        <aside class="sidebar">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </aside>
       </div>
     </body>
   </html>
```

I have no idea why the calc function is not working and not adding the 1.5em gutter, please help

Comment: Is this how you imagine it to be: https://jsfiddle.net/TRNCFRMCN/hq39gu0L/1/ ? I only added content to the `sidebar div`. 

Comment: That's how it displays in my browser but with a margin of 1% or 1.5em. Yours does not have a margin between the 2 containers either. In a nutshell, I want a 1% margin i.e. margin-left: 1% in the second container and the first to separate them. I did it by making the the aside have a margin-left: 1% and width:29% but I do not want to hard code the width so I used the calc to do that

Comment: Got it. You had the `float:left` at the `.sidebar`.  https://jsfiddle.net/TRNCFRMCN/hq39gu0L/2/ does this bring you further? 

Comment: Yes, it does, the margin I want is 1.5em so I want to use width:calc(30% - 1.5em) but that did not work. You solution is quite close!

Comment: Is there a reason for using float rather than more modern methods like flex or grid?

Comment: Well, this is some code that I have to fix without changing the current method, just to fix increase the margin to 1.5 em, so that's why I'm not using flex

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/TRNCFRMCN/hq39gu0L/3/ .

Comment: That is exactly what I want. Thank you very much!  Why does calc(30% - 1.5em) not work but calc(-1.5em + 30%) ? The spec indicates that the former should work

Comment: calc(100% - 1.5em) does work - but make sure you have spaces either side of the minus sign.

Comment: You are welcome. To be true, i got more than two years `CSS`. But to understand `calc` i need more than two years again. Here it works. https://jsfiddle.net/TRNCFRMCN/hq39gu0L/4/